# Changing permissions

Tags: permissions

In the fedora docs they refer to owner and group owner as if both are owners of the file.  The leads me to think that any member of a group which tries to change permissions of a file owned by that group will be allowed.  Is this right, or can only the "owner" in it's most absolute sense change permissions?

Example

User foo group bar
User pc group bar

Can pc change a file creates by foo and group bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the owner (not the group owner) of a file could change its permissions.

The group owner is only used to establish what access permissions have other users of the same group, other than the file owner.

Permissions are not stored on the directory, so you don't need write permissions on the containing directory.

Comment: just have one quick question, when you say permissions are not stored on the directory, can you be more specific.  I always though even directories had permissions?

Comment: @rubixibuc It means that you don't need write permission on a directory to change the permissions of any files inside it.  The only actions you need write permissions on a directory for are creating / deleting / renaming directory entries.